# Получить значение data атрибута через each при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть карточки постов и в них есть кнопки поделиться, нравиться и добавить в закладки, мне нужно получить значение **data-post-uid** у класса **js-feed-post** через клик у класса **like**. Вот кусочек кода:

```
<div class="js-feed-post" data-post-uid="dls3xu56ke">
    <div class="t-feed-footer">
        <div class="t-feed_icon like"></div>
    </div>      
</div>

<script>
$(window).load(function() {
$('.js-feed-post').each(function (index, item) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var post_uid = $(this).attr("data-post-uid");
        console.log(post_uid);
        return false;
    });
});
$('.like').each(function (index, value) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active-like");
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, должно сработать.

```js
// $(window).load был удалён с версии 3.0
// Лучше его не использовать
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.like').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-like");
    
    let uid = $(this)      // Кнопка
                            .parent()  // Футер карточки
                .parent()  // Карточка
                .attr("data-post-uid");
    
    // Мы что-нибудь делаем с результатом
    alert("You liked post " + uid);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.js-feed-post {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="js-feed-post" data-post-uid="dls3xu56ke">
  <p>The post</p>
  <div class="t-feed-footer">
    <button class="like t-feed_icon">Like</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Дабы избежать привязки к структуре html, советую вместо .parent().parent() воспользоваться .closest('.js-feed-post')

Comment: @radar4ick Спасибо! На самом деле, я не очень хорошо знаком с JQuery.